# How can I create new pages for users to fill out in buddypress?

Tags: new-operator, buddypress

I can create new pages as the admin, but when I sign in as a simple user, I can't. I added links to user bar and would like to make it possible for the users to add information about themselves on those pages. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With other admin panels, there is usually a permissions feature, for example, forums have set permissions for standard users. Maybe you should look into the permissions of visitors and see if you can alter it for them to be able to post.

Comment: The thing is I don't give them the ability to create unlimited amount of pages. I want them to have the possibility to fill in the 10 or so new categories I have created in the profile loop before. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the said profile loop so I can have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry it was the functions.php after all. I learned about the code on some forum:

    global $bp;
 if(!bp_is_home())
 $bp->bp_nav[110]=array ( 'name' => 'Ideas','link' => 'www.pageonmysite.org/', 'css_id' =>'Ideas','show_for_displayed_user' => 1 ,'position' => 110 );

So I've created a link on the user bar called "Ideas" that leads to whatever I put in the brackets in "link" above. What I'm trying to do is make it a personal page for the user to edit and other users to comment on.

Comment: If its a feature that allows users to log on to a unique page, you're going to require some form of database, MySQL may be the way of going through a hosting package that supports it, then allow the users to edit the page maybe using said sql code or maybe a CMS, have a look at some of these: http://spyrestudios.com/free-content-management-systems/

Comment: I'm actually using wordpress as a CMS and my site is built on a plugin called buddypress. Could you be more specific in how can I use MySQL to create the mentioned pages?